# How to Mock webclient with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have this in my app. An ENDPOINT , which calls an external api-rest.
Some EXamples:
public class CallApiRest {

```
private String url;
private String path;

private WebClient webClient;


public ResponseEntity<Flux<CandidateRequestAssigned>> get (String url,String path){
     webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();

    return  ResponseEntity.ok( webClient.get()
            .uri(path)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 400 Bad request");
            })
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,response -> {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 500 error");  
            })
            .bodyToFlux(CandidateRequestAssigned.class)
            .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofMillis(2000))));

}

public ResponseEntity<Mono<CandidateRequestAssigned>> delete (String url,String path ,String id){
    webClient = WebClient.create(url);

    return  ResponseEntity.ok( webClient.delete()
            .uri(path + "/" + id)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 400 Bad request");
            })
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,response -> {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 500 error"); 
            })
            .bodyToMono(CandidateRequestAssigned.class));

}
```

}

But I'm not sure how to pass junit5's test. my app just makes a call endpoint in the controller to call the .get(), .delete() function

Example:
@GetMapping("/callApiGet")
public ResponseEntity<Flux> callApiGet(@Valid @RequestBody CallApiRequest callApiRequest) {
CallApiRest callApiRest = new CallApiRest();
return  callApiRest.get(callApiRequest.getUrl(),callApiRequest.getPath());
}

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).